# positioning of Google Captcha works fine on desktop / tablet, but not on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML :

```
   <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 7%;" id="gCaptcha">
     @Html.Recaptcha("MyKey", CaptchaTheme.Dark)
     @Html.ValidationMessage("ReCaptcha")
   </div>
```

As you can see I have specified margin-left:7% reason behind this is because I want it to appear in the middle instead of floating to the left as shown here:

[image]

this works fine on desktop / tablets but when viewed on a mobile device its pushed further to the right because of the margin-left:7% i have specified, now to fix this I assumed I could of put margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto but that doesn't do anything, can anyone suggest a way that will make this captcha appear in the middle for all devices?

Answer (score 1):

Hello there try this in your [@media](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) for phones:

**Important inline-styles will overwrite any other css**

***remove*** style="margin-left: 7%;"

```
#gCaptcha{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 85%;
}
```

If this doesn't work please provide the CSS for .form-group